# Pagination not rendered for angular-ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using below version-
angularjs 1.2.18
bootstrap 3.3.2
ui.bootstrap 0.12.0

I declared the dependencies in my config file but when I try to use the pagination tag in HTML it is not rendered.In my HTML its showing Unknown HTML tag pagination but that's OK I guess since it ll be rendered by Angularjs during compilation.

Is there any problem with the versions ?

Comment: Do you have any console error ?

Comment: Need to post your controller model code and html structure. We have no idea if your directive is in proper scope or not. Also did you include the templates version of ui.bootstrap ?

Comment: We are using require.js to load all the js files which declares all the js.  config.js-> require.config({  paths: { 'ui.bootstrap.tpls': 'webjars/angular-ui-bootstrap/' + angularBootstrapUiVersion + '/ui-bootstrap-tpls' + dotMin},shim: {'ui.bootstrap.tpls':{
            deps: ['angular']
        },
      'appModule': {
        deps: ['angular', 'jquery', 'bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap','ui.bootstrap.tpls']
      } }  appmodule is my module- which is a separate js file,  my search.html only includes -<script data-main="config" src="webjars/requirejs/2.1.8/require.js"></script>